# Facebook Api: Como obter feed de uma página utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk, api

Estou tentando puxar os posts de uma página no facebook e exibir eles em um site, o que preciso principalmente é da foto e da legenda de cada post.

Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/facebook-php-graph-sdk-5/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/facebook-php-graph-sdk-5/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php';

/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
print_r($graphObject);
/* handle the result */
?>
```

E eu estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRequest' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\site\wp-content\themes\tema\functions.php on line 7
```

Como eu estou inserindo o FaacebookRequest.php e tá dizendo que a Class 'FacebookRequest' not found ?

Eu nunca fiz isso antes e estou tendo duvidas pra começar, estou pesquisando e lendo a documentação, e mesmo assim estou tendo dificuldade de entender a documentação, o que tá me ajudando mais são as perguntas que acho em fóruns e artigos independentes.

Não precisa responder tudo mastigado, se tiver algum link onde eu possa encontrar a resposta já ficarei imensamente grato.

### ATUALIZAÇÃO:

Continuei pesquisando e consegui fazer da seguinte forma, através da documentação do próprio facebook:

```
<?php
require_once 'inc/facebook-php-graph-sdk-5/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '***********',
  'app_secret' => '*********************',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
  ]);

$response = $fb->get('/PAGE-NAME/feed', 'ACCESS-TOKEN-AQUI');

print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: Da uma olhada na introdução da documentação do [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted). Eles usam namespaces, então sua a invocação da classe teria que ser parecido com isso:
`new Facebook\FacebookRequest()`.